# Multivalue search to find index number in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array stored in **$data** variable:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [delivery_plan] => 2021/07
            [code] => CR020
            [amount] => 250
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [delivery_plan] => 2021/08
            [code] => CR020
            [amount] => 350
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [delivery_plan] => 2021/09
            [code] => CR020
            [amount] => 100
        )
```

I'd like to find the numeric index by using the values of "delivery_plan" and "code".
For example the delivery plan = 2021/09 AND code = CR020 then the expected result is 2.

The code i've been using so far :

```
function searchForId($delivery_plan, $code, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
       if ($arr['delivery_plan'] === $delivery_plan && $arr['code'] === $code) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return null;
}

$id = searchForId('2021/06','CR020', $data);
print_r($id);
```

I've tried using loops and the result was fine (2) , however **i don't want to using any loops** for this case

What is the faster/better solution other than using the loops ?

Comment: Again, this is somewhat context dependent. If you need to figure out one value dynamically each time the script runs you could fall back onto [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), if you are sure there is only one match you can use an [array_key_first](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php) to get the index. If you access the array on different key combinations multiple times you might alter the original array for constant time access by keys. (array filter will nonetheless iterate over all items in the array)

Comment: Although array_filter will loop over the entire array whereas in your current function you return immediately when you found the value which might win you a few cycles.